# Error Requested information not in dictionary

Tags: dictionary, teradata, restore

Recently I had to restore the dictionary backup of a database that has tables and a bunch of stored procedures using ABU. After the restore, I wasn't able to look at the definition of the tables / stored procedures. I was getting the error "Requested Information not in Dictionary". I then ran the BUILD command on the database. After that I was able to access the tables, however accessing the SPs still threw the same error. When I checked the logs, the BUILD was done only on the tables , not on the stored procedures. I then ran the BUILD command on individual procedures which worked, however I still was not able to look at the definition of the procedure. Was getting the same error. Finally I re-compiled the procs. So I have couple questions here

1) Why the BUILD database command did not work for procedures? Do we need to do individually?
2) Why did I get the same error despite running the BUILD on stored procedures. How can I restore procs without having to compile them again?

Thanks

Comment: Stored procedures have data associated with them. A dictionary restore alone is not enough to rebuild them.

Comment: Thanks for the response Rob. So does that mean that we can only do a data restore with procs and not a dictionary restore?

Comment: Could someone please clarify this?

Comment: Either recompile them or restore from database backup.